# Showing or hiding the keyboard in a WebView depending on the focused element in Android

Tags: android, webview, view, keyboard

I have a screen where I have a WebView and in the received page I get a handful of fields, including “EditTexts” and some calendar fields. The problem is that whenever a calendar field is clicked, the keyboard pops up. I would like to somehow determine what kind of field is clicked in the WebView and based on that, display or hide the keyboard.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

PS. The only answers I could find regarding WebViews concerned the entire WebView - I want something that gives me the ability to discern what kind of view it is "selected" in the WebView and based on that to show or hide the keyboard.

Comment: What do you mean by "calendar fields"? Inside the `WebView` you will have html. So, to what kind of html element are you referring?

Comment: I basically have a page loaded in a WebView, with different form fields that need to be completed for a registration flow. Some of these fields are "calendar fields" in the sense that when you press in that field, a calendar pops up allowing you to select a day. The Android keyboard also pops up, over the calendar widget, so you have to hide the keyboard first and then you'll see the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

How can you handle the HTML of the page with the native behavior of the android? You are using a webview that will load the HTML page as defined in the server. You cannot control the web elements of that webpage with the hardware or the software in your native platform.

If you still have to do this. You need to target the HTML tags via some HTML parser. Go through **JSoup** library and start targetting the elements of the webpage and then you can control the keyboard of your platform using **InputMethodManager**